# PHP POPUP AJAX Query wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**this is the viewpage js code :**

```
$('#insertbarang').on('click',function(){
                var form = $('#form_insert_barang').serializeArray();
                form.push({name: "key",value:"insertbarang"});
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/ajax/ajax.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:form,
                    success:function(msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error:function(msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
```

**this is ajax file :**

```
    <?php  

include("../pages/mod/connect.php");

$pass = false;
$post = $_POST;

switch ($post['key']) {
    case "insertbarang":

        $result1 = executeQuery("select qty from msbarang where idbarang='".$post['idbarang']."'");

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

        if($row[0]-$post['qty']>=0){

        $row[0]=$row[0]-$post['qty'];

        unset($post['key']);
        $q = "START TRANSACTION;";
        $q .= "INSERT INTO `trbarang` SET idbarang = '".$post['idbarang']."', qty = '".$post['qty']."', harga='".$post['harga']."', status = '".$post['status']."';";
        $q .= "Update msbarang set qty='".$row[0]."' where idbarang='".$post['idbarang']."';";
        $q .= "COMMIT;";


        if($data = executeQuery($q)){
            $pass = true;
        }

        }


        break;
    default:
        break;
}



if($pass){
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    return false;
}

?>
```

i want to submit data from popup page there is success alerted but the query not work no data was inserted.

Comment: You're not checking your SQL result for errors.  What is logged to the console?  What does `executeQuery()` return?  The code is wide open to SQL injection, which means that resulting SQL query could be just about anything.  Check for errors from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code

```
if($pass){
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

will always return a successful HTTP response so the ajax call will just go to success.

You should do something like

```
echo json_encode(array('passed' => $pass, 'data' => $data));
```

and check for the passed in the ajax success.

Also check what you have in the `$post`, it seems that this piece `form.push({name: "key",value:"insertbarang"});` will produce `['name' => 'key', 'value' => 'insertbarang']` instead of `['key' => 'insertbarang']` so the `$post['key']` does not exist at all.